# Axios - can we use onUploadProgress and onDownloadProgress for json data?

Tags: reactjs, axios

What are the disadvantages in using `onUploadProgress` and `onDownloadProgress` in axios for json data? Because I have mostly seen people use it for file upload..

Does it only serve for file down or upload purposes? What other use cases do `onUploadProgress` an `onDownloadProgress` have?

Comment: JSON Data behaves the same as a file does, so is there really a difference in behaviour?

Comment: No..my question is does onUploadProgress create a delay from frontend dealing with json data,since there is no use of onUploadProgress for json unlike form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What are the disadvantages in using onUploadProgress and onDownloadProgress in axios for json data?**

If you have the right use case and you want to show the user how fast or slow the json uploads/downloads there is absolutely no disadvantage, most of times you would use json to build your dom though, so there are more appropriate ways to check if the dom has been built or not.

**Does it only serve for file down or upload purposes?**

I would say 99% of the time. As the documentation states:

> One difference that may end up being a show-stopper for some is
>   progress updates on uploads/downloads. As Axios is built on top of the
>   older XHR API, you’re able to register callback functions for
>   onUploadProgress and onDownloadProgress to display the percentage
>   complete in your app’s UI. Currently, Fetch has no support for doing
>   this.

**What other use cases do onUploadProgress an onDownloadProgress have?**

You could also start a upload/download to check connection speeds between the user and your server. Even though this is probably not the best way either.

**Does onUploadProgress create a delay from frontend dealing with json data**

[The documentation](https://www.sitepoint.com/axios-beginner-guide/) doesn't imply it would cause any delays.

Comment: could you please add a link to the documentation, thanks for the good answer